# com.andorid.volley.AuthFailureError in using volley library

Tags: android, post, mobile, android-volley

I am new in android studio and be going to use volley library to get data from server.
I have used following code:

```
JSONObject request_body = new JSONObject();
try {
    request_body.put("method", "authenticate");
    request_body.put("id", "1");
    request_body.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
    JSONArray params = new JSONArray();
    params.put(user_name);
    params.put(password);
    request_body.put("params", params);
} catch(Exception e) {

}

RequestQueue requestQueueV1= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
JsonObjectRequest stringRequestV1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url + AppConfig.VERSION1_URL, request_body, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

     }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.d("MainActivity", error.toString());
           Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
stringRequestV1.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(4000, 2, 2f));
requestQueueV1.add(stringRequestV1);
```

But I have got error: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Following is my postman screenshot:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Don't post text as images

Answer (score -1):

Pass Header parameter and you will get response